# Наследование. Каким образом вызывается operator=() через оператор разрешения контекста?

Tags: c++, наследование

Читал про наследование с динамическим выделением памяти одновременно: и в производном, и в базовом классах. И есть такая штука в примере с определением operator=() производного класса:

```
BaseClass::operator=(derived_reference);
```

Как так? Ведь operator=() - не статический метод, а значит его вызывать можно только через объект. Ниже написано, что это почти равнозначно следующему:

```
*this = derived_reference;
```

Только в этом случае будет рекурсивный вызов, т.к. будет преобразовано в:

```
DerivedClass::operator=(derived_reference);
```

Это такая особенность, созданная для наследования, или как? Ведь по правилам, на сколько я знаю, так делать никак нельзя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужно вызвать перегруженную функцию , но базовый вариант, то синтаксис такой : `дочерний_объект.Имя_базового_класса::Имя_функции(...)`. Всё можно. Вы читали про виртуальные методы, где сначала анализируется тип главного объекта, а затем вызывается определённый метод. Вот пример **не**-виртуального присвоения.

```
# include <iostream>

class DerivedClass  ;

class BaseClass {
  int b{};
public :
BaseClass & operator  = ( BaseClass const & ) ;
BaseClass & operator  = ( DerivedClass const & ) ;
} ;

class DerivedClass : public BaseClass  {
  int d{};
public:
DerivedClass  & operator  = (BaseClass const & );
DerivedClass  & operator  = (DerivedClass const & );
};

BaseClass & BaseClass :: operator  = ( BaseClass const & x ) {
  std::cout<<"BaseClass :: operator  = ( BaseClass const & x )\n";
  b = x.b;
  return * this ; }

BaseClass & BaseClass :: operator  = ( DerivedClass const & x ) {
  std::cout<<"BaseClass :: operator  = ( DerivedClass const & x )\n";
  b = x.b;
  return * this ; }

DerivedClass  & DerivedClass :: operator  = (BaseClass const & x ) {
  std::cout<<"DerivedClass :: operator  = (BaseClass const & x )\n";
  this -> BaseClass :: operator  = ( x ) ;
  return  * this  ; }

DerivedClass  & DerivedClass :: operator  = (DerivedClass const & x ) {
  std::cout<<"DerivedClass :: operator  = (DerivedClass const & x )\n";
  this -> BaseClass :: operator  = ( x ) ;
  d = x.d ;
  return * this ; }

int main(){
  BaseClass b ;
  DerivedClass  d ;
  std::cout<<"d = b ;\n";
  d = b ;
  std::cout<<"d = d ;\n";
  d = d ;
  std::cout<<"b = b ;\n";
  b = b ;
  std::cout<<"b = d ;\n";
  b = d ; }
```

Результат :

```
d = b ;
DerivedClass :: operator  = (BaseClass const & x )
BaseClass :: operator  = ( BaseClass const & x )
d = d ;
DerivedClass :: operator  = (DerivedClass const & x )
BaseClass :: operator  = ( DerivedClass const & x )
b = b ;
BaseClass :: operator  = ( BaseClass const & x )
b = d ;
BaseClass :: operator  = ( DerivedClass const & x )
```

Comment: Вот такой синтаксис кажется куда более понятным , хотя и необычным: this->BaseClass::operator=(derref);

Comment: В примере вызывается без this, что меня смутило, я этого не понял. Да, я уже прочитал и понял, что такое абстрактный базовый класс и чистая виртуальная функция. Но вот с этим что-то пока не разобрался. Всё таки, ведь нельзя вызывать operator=() в явном виде без оператора обращения к члену (прямого или косвенного)?

Comment: Можно с `this->` а можно и без. Внутри метода класса, по-умолчанию используются методы данного класса и с ссылкой на себя (`this`).

Comment: Я думал это только к данным-членам относится.

Comment: Приходится иногда писать этот `this->` чтобы точно не перепутать со статическими функциями. Редко, но бывает.

Comment: Я просто всегда писал через this, иначе можно подумать, что это просто функция, а не метод. Мне кажется правильно писать через оператор обращения к члену.

Comment: @AlexGlebe: "...чтобы точно не перепутать со статическими функциями" - это как это? Как это вам поможет "не перепутать"? Статические функции класса тоже можно вызывать через `this->`, хоть `this` им и не нужен.

Comment: @AnT Статические я имел в виду, в глобальном пространстве имён. Чтобы точно её вызвать нужно `::f()`, а чтобы точно не перепутать классовым методом `this->f()` или `A::f()` для статических.

Answer (score 3):

> Как так? Ведь operator=() - не статический метод, а значит его вызывать можно только через объект.

Когда вы находитесь в контексте определения метода класса, вам совсем не обязательно указывать объект при обращении к членам класса. В таком контексте всякий раз, когда поиск имен (name lookup) находит имя члена класса, он автоматически подразумевает, что речь идет о доступе через объект `*this`. Это настолько общеизвестное и повсеместно используемое правило, что меня безмерно удивляет ваш вопрос.

Вот в таком примере

```
struct S
{  
  void foo() {}
  void bar() { foo(); }
};
```

в определении метода `bar()` мы вызываем `this->foo()` просто как `foo()`. Если вас это не удивляет, то почему вас удивляет то, что вместо

```
this->BaseClass::operator=(derived_reference);
```

мы можем написать просто

```
BaseClass::operator=(derived_reference);
```

?

То, что в данном случае мы использовали квалифицированное имя члена класса (т.е. имя с явным указанием `BaseClass::`) абсолютно ничего не меняет.

> Ниже написано, что это почти равнозначно следующему:
>
> ```
> *this = derived_reference;
> ```
>
> Только в этом случае будет рекурсивный вызов

Совершенно верно. Избежать бесконечной рекурсии и достичь желаемого поведения можно также через

```
DerivedClass &operator =(const DerivedClass &derived_reference)
{
  BaseClass *base_this = this;
  *base_this = derived_reference;
  ...
}
```

или даже через

```
using BaseClass::operator =;
DerivedClass &operator =(const DerivedClass &derived_reference)
{
  const BaseClass &base_reference = derived_reference;
  *this = base_reference;
  ...
}
```

но все эти способы более громоздки, чем исходный вариант.

Надо заметить, что эти варианты, в отличие от исходного варианта с квалифицированным именем, не подавляют виртуальности вызова метода. Вряд ли кому-то придет в голову писать виртуальный оператор присваивания, но в случае других методов, оказавшихся в аналогичной ситуации, это - важная и полезная деталь.

> Это такая особенность, созданная для наследования, или как? Ведь по правилам, на сколько я знаю, так делать никак нельзя.

О каких "правилах" вы говорите?

Comment: Я же говорю, я думал что это применимо только для данных-членов (полей), но не для функций-членов (методов). Да, меня это ввело в ступор, когда я это увидел в примере. Спасибо за разъяснение.

Comment: Кстати, когда в книге по Си++ (Прата) объяснялось, что такое указатель this и для чего он нужен, одной из причин называлась как раз возможность вызова методов. Было сказано, что можно для полей опускать. А вот на счёт методов ничего не говорилось. Вот я и писал всегда явно. И мне до сих пор кажется, что так правильнее. Метод как раз и отличается от функции тем, что вызывается через объект. Если это не очевидно, то это может ввести в заблуждение. Ведь для полей , как правило, используются специальные идентификаторы, а вот для методов это не годится.

Comment: @Παν μέτρον άριστον: Что-то я сомневаюсь, что Прата имел в виду именно это, т.е. безусловное использование `this->` при вызове методов. Это было бы очень странным советом и очень странной практикой. Особенно при проведении такого явного различия с полями.